# jquery checkbox check not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I have a small script,with very straight function. If the checkbox is not checked, if the user clicked on it show a div otherwise hide the div when user clicks in it. The script is (its inside a PHP code ):

```
echo 
'<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("#chk_id'.$bank_name.'").is(":checked"))
{


   $("#chk_id'.$bank_name.'").click(function(){
      $("#form_show'.$bank_name.'").hide(300);
   });

}
else
{ 

    $("#chk_id'.$bank_name.'").click(function(){

    //alert("ddd");

    $("#form_show'.$bank_name.'").show(300);
   });
}
});    


</script>';
```

But the problem is although the show div is working, I am unable to hide the div ! Whats wrong?
javascript library : `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Show us your example in JSFiddle

Comment: And if you could add your html code too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', "#chk_id'.$bank_name.'", function() {
        if($("#chk_id'.$bank_name.'").is(":checked")) {
            $("#form_show'.$bank_name.'").hide(300);
        } else {
            $("#form_show'.$bank_name.'").show(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your function should be something like this:

```
function checkBankName(){
    if($("#chk_id'.$bank_name.'").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#form_show'.$bank_name.'").show(300);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#form_show'.$bank_name.'").hide(300);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // first time
    checkBankName();

    // on check
    $("#chk_id'.$bank_name.'").click(function(){
        checkBankName();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MsPJN/1/)

```
 $("#chk_id").click(function(){
       if($('#chk_id:checked').length > 0){
          $('.bank_name').hide(300);
       }
       else{
          $('.bank_name').show(300);
       }
   });
```

I have guessed your html implementation. You may not need to include the `#form_show` in your selector.

Or, you could do something like this using toggle:

[tioggle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MsPJN/2/)

```
// code to initialize state before click

$("#chk_id").click(function(){    
    $('.bank_name').toggle(300);            
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of another answer here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chk_id' . $bank_name . '").change(function() {
        $("#form_show' . $bank_name . '")[this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'](300);
    }).change();
});
```